# Why won't the Cytoscape app "iRegulon" finish analyses?

Tags: cytoscape

I have been using the app iRegulon to analyze transcription factor activity. In order to do this, I input a gene list and after selecting the genes, go to the iRegulon app and select "predict regulators and targets". After hitting "OK" in the next dialog box, the loading screen gets stuck on "Waiting until other jobs are finished..." I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the iRegulon app and Cytoscape. See below for the task history following and attempt at analysis:

 Untitled (edu.ucsf.rbvi.cyBrowser.internal.tasks.DialogTask)

 iRegulon analysis: Sheet1
 Starting request
 Requesting server...
 Waiting until other jobs are finished...
 Waiting until other jobs are finished...
 Waiting until other jobs are finished...
 Waiting until other jobs are finished...
 Waiting until other jobs are finished...
 Waiting until other jobs are finished...
 Waiting until other jobs are finished...
 Waiting until other jobs are finished...
 Waiting until other jobs are finished...
 Waiting until other jobs are finished...
 Waiting until other jobs are finished...
 Waiting until other jobs are finished...
 Waiting until other jobs are finished...
 Waiting until other jobs are finished...
 Waiting until other jobs are finished...
 Waiting until other jobs are finished...

Answer (score 0):

The problem should be fixed and jobs should be able to run again. Sometimes jobs that can't be processed correctly block the queue.